# IBM WebSphere Host On-Demand (HoD): How can I do that using macros?

Tags: websphere

If I cannot fix the problem related to [IBM WebSphere Host On-Demand (HoD): Cannot run program with "runprogram" command. What can I do?](https://superuser.com/questions/280926/ibm-host-on-demand-cannot-run-program-with-runprogram-command-what-can-i-do) , I would like to know another way to do that in an IBM Host on Demand client:

```
T: txt file with all registers I want (numeric values)

begin
    while don't reach end of T
    begin
        R=read one register in T
        execute commands using R
        S=capture string value from a known location on screen
        stores S on a file, F (appending or creating F1.txt, F2.txt, F3.txt...)
    end;
end.
```

Well, I think that question is for SuperUser, because it uses only few programming skills - a man can use macros without programming knowledge...